# Magento2: WYSIWYG / TinyMCE Editor every time removing <a> tags in CMS blocks

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, static-block, wysiwyg

I am adding HTML in CMS block editor but it keeps removing `<a>` tags from Html.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: This is Magento's issue which is still open. #4536

Comment: So, we don't have any solution for now?

Comment: To fix this, You need to fix your HTML and TinyMCE will not complain. In this case, try replacing the <div> tags with <span> tags, as <div> tags are (officially) not valid inside <a> tags, as they are not in-line elements. TinyMCE does not like that, so it just removes the <a> tag for you.

Comment: In Magento 2.3 there will be releasing an upgrade to TinyMCE to boost us to v4. This means we could then enable allow_html_in_named_anchor (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#allow_html_in_named_anchor) to resolve the issue with anchor specifically.

Comment: can you paste your html code here?

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible solution for this

Go this file: `lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/html5-schema.js`

Replace this:

```
['a', 'href target rel media hreflang type charset name rev shape coords download', phrasingContent],
```

With this:

```
['a', 'href target rel media hreflang type charset name rev shape coords download', flowContent],
```

Good approach to override this file is you can do this some thing like that

`app/design/adminhtml/YourCustomthemeName/Backend/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/html5-schema.js`

The reason this fixes the issue is that the `flowContent` array includes block level tags and inline tags unlike the `phrasingContent` array which includes only inline elements.

The first element of this array is the a the tag we want to fix, the second array entry appears to be attributes allowed on a tags, and the third array entry (the one we care about) appears to be allowed children.

Another solution is to update Magento version to 2.3 because Magento 2.3 will finally have an update to Tinymce 4.x as @Aaditya suggested you in comment.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/web/tiny_mce_4/tinymce.min.js

**I hope this will help**
**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where I can find this 'html5-schema.js' in core files? I am working on Magento2.3

Comment: I shared the path in answer as well. You have to go to `YourMagentofolder/lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/html5-schema.js`

Comment: @Shiwani have you found the file? if yes then in order to test that changes work, just do answer mentioned changes in core file `html5-schema.js`. After it resolved issue then after override the file the way, I described in the answer

Comment: No, This is not working. I override the file and run the commands.

Comment: Don't override it, just edit the core file `YourMagentofolder/lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/html5-schema.js` and run the commands. check whether changes resolve the issue or not if yes then try to override the file because there may be the issue in directory structure in overriding the file

Comment: Okay, Let me check again

Comment: @Shiwani Did it work or not?

Comment: I am working on it. When I get resolved will definitely update you

Comment: @MuhammadHasham nice easy solution, It worked for me. +1

Comment: @shiwani have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue, this can be solved by configuring `valid_elements` and `valid_children` settings inside `Tinymce4Adapter.js` file(for TinyMCE version 4.6)

As answered by https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/77224/mike-dubs here [Magento 2.3 - TinyMCE4 Toolbar and Plugin Configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263745/magento-2-3-tinymce4-toolbar-and-plugin-configuration/263891)
create the module as mentioned there and add below code inside Config plugin file to provide `valid_elements and valid_children` settings to `Tinymce4Adapter.js` as shown below

```
$settings['valid_elements'] = '*[*]';
$settings['valid_children'] = '+body[style],+div[a],+p[strong|a|#text],+a[div]';
```

Thanks!