# How to create custom plugin for TinyMCE 4

Tags: magento2, custom, plugin, tinymce

I'm trying to add ability to create custom forms with TinyMCE 4 but can't understand how to do it properly. I should create my custom plugin and then connect it to editor, but can't find any useful information. Tried answer from this thread [Magento 2.3 - TinyMCE4 Toolbar and Plugin Configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263745/magento-2-3-tinymce4-toolbar-and-plugin-configuration) but i can't add my custom plugin by this way. Magento devdocs also don't give me any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4
and add this module to extend tinymce4 will work
https://github.com/quannh02/tinimce4

Comment: My goal is to create custom .js plugin for TinyMCE 4 (standard wisywyg editor in magento 2.3) and make it appear in toolbar. Your answer is not working for custom plugins.